# Avro ClassCastException when running crunch job on hadoop 2

Tags: hadoop

I've written a crunch hadoop job that runs perfectly with tests. All tests pass. However, when I try to run it on the command line, I get a backtrace containing this exception during the reduce phase:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to com.person.Person
```

I'm invoking it with the following on my mac:

```
hadoop jar target/job-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar uk.co.person.Offer -Dinput=file:///tmp/input/part-m-00000.avro -Doutput=/tmp/output
```

I didn't have this problem with hadoop 1.0.3.

From research, it seems that the problem is that the reducer can't find my Person class, even though all dependencies are in the jar.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Interesting. It not needed but what if you push your jar with the -libjar option too?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker I get the same error when adding `-libjar=target/job-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` to the end of the hadoop command

Comment: I think, we don't need the '=' after the -libjar, if you are using that. One more thing I noticed, if you are using 'input' as a property key, you must have a space between -D and 'input'.

Comment: if you can post the MR driver code, it would help us to figure out the problem faster.